# Spyder - console command prompt changed from >>> to In : after help('modules') command

Tags: python, windows-7, module, spyder

I ran `help('modules')` on the Spyder console, to find all of my installed modules.

Before I ran it the prompt looked like:

```
>>>
```

After it ran (it worked). It looked like:

```
In :
```

The behaviour seems the same. For example

```
>>> x=1
>>> x
1
>>>
```

vs:

```
In : x=1
In : x
1
In :
```

Can anyone explain this? Can anyone repeat it? Does anyone know how to exit this mode? Is it to do with the command (`help('modules')`) or Spyder?

OS: *Win7*

*Spyder 2.2.5*

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is that this is caused by the behavior of one of your modules. Check this blog post:

http://mostlycode.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/modules-that-block-pythons-help/

(just ignore all the "it's")

Answer (score 1):

It does have to to with the Python help built-in function.  To get out of it, simply type `quit`.  For more information, check out [the Python page of built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#help). The `In:` in Spyder simply means that the program (here the `help` module) is asking for input.

**EDIT:** [Here](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/internalconsole.html?highlight=help) is some more Spyder-specific console info.

Comment: Thanks. For me, when I type `quit` it comes back with `Use quit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit`. If I press Ctrl-Z plus Return it returns the `In :` prompt again. If I type `quit()`, it hangs...

Comment: Weird.  I can't reproduce the problem. I'm also running Spyder 2.2.5, but on Windows 8.  `help('modules'` gives me a bunch of `DeprecationWarning`s but it doesn't actually start the Python `help` interpreter.  What version of Python are you running? This is a Python rather than a Spyder thing

Comment: Hmm.  Are you using an IPython console?  The prompt for IPython is `In:`

Comment: Running Python 2.7.6. I don't think it's IPython - I thought IPython prompt was `In [1]:`, `In [2]:` etc. Also I did start off with the `>>>` prompt.